# Convert year, week into date based on year's first day in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have sum of all week sales into one object and object need to display in charts and all chart need to have date in x-axis so,
Here I am calculating date from year+week based on Monday

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('20131',' Monday'), '%X%V %W');
```

I want it based on first day on year

```
SELECT DAYNAME(MAKEDATE(2013,1))
```

All togather

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(2013, 1), DAYNAME(MAKEDATE(2013,1))), '%X%V %W')
```

return '2013-01-08' which is bad value I need '2013-01-01'

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CONCAT(2017, 1), DAYNAME(MAKEDATE(2017,1))), '%X%V %W')
```

here it return '2017-01-01' which is good

My problem is in some years it went to next week which is bad
I am not sure where and what I am doing wrong ...
So Please any kind of help...

Problem:

In some year like 2013 when I convert year+ week to date I get date in one extra week like 2013year+ 1week gives 2013-01-08 which is in second week instead of first

but

In some year like 2017 when I convert year+ week to date I get date in right week like 2017year+ 1week gives 2017-01-01

Why is this behavior?

Comment: Its is really unclear what you are trying to accomplish....can you elaborate a little more on the problem?

Comment: mySQL gives one week extra while converting year+week to date for some years and for some its good...This behavior is my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL supports intervals which seems to be the best feature for creating a date from a year and week number. See the following query as an example which calculates the first week of 2013 and the second week of 2013.

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(makedate(`year`, 1), INTERVAL (`week` - 1) WEEK) as weekdate
FROM (
   (SELECT 2013 as `year`, 1 as `week`) UNION 
   (SELECT 2013 as `year`, 2 as `week`)
) t1
```

The output is two rows

```
weekdate
2013-01-01
2013-01-08
```

The following also works but is far less easy to read

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(`year`, 1 + ((`week` - 1) * 7)) as weekdate 
FROM (
    (SELECT 2013 as `year`, 1 as `week`) UNION 
    (SELECT 2013 as `year`, 2 as `week`)
) t1
```

Comment: Thanks man it works best... as you can see it took me to 2 days to see that solution is what I want. I up voted and Thanks again.